# Errors installing KDESVN and kde-runtime

Tags: apt, kde, dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install kdesvn
```

returns:

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... 
Done Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the 
unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:    
kdesvn : Depends: kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed    
Recommends: kompare but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

when I run: `sudo apt-get install kdesvn`

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... 
Done Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable 
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 kde-runtime : Depends: kdelibs5-plugins (>= 4:4.14.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: plasma-scriptengine-javascript (= 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libkdeclarative5 (>= 4:4.9.80) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libkdesu5 (>= 4:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libkdewebkit5 (>= 4:4.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libkdnssd4 (>= 4:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libkemoticons4 (>= 4:4.4.95) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libkfile4 (>= 4:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libkmediaplayer4 (>= 4:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libknewstuff3-4 (>= 4:4.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libknotifyconfig4 (>= 4:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libkpty4 (>= 4:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libplasma3 (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed 
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I used `aptitude` to solve the problem

```
sudo aptitude install kdesvn
```

Just search for the best solution that aptitude gives you...